# Models in a separate C# Project or Same?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a C# MVC Net Core Application.

Reading some books, some are telling to write Database Models in their own project. Others are saying Not to have Database Models in their own project. Just curious what benefits/advantages are derived from placing models in own project?
The question Does 'Not need to be asked in reverse. I am just asking the benefits of separating models? (This question is not opinion based, and will not be asking for a recommendation, just functional benefits for this way)

Comment: https://programmingwithmosh.com/csharp/should-you-split-your-asp-net-mvc-project-into-multiple-projects/ Check this article

Comment: why did they vote down question? trying to learn, thanks for the link by the way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Kindly check it to ask a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary advantage to placing your database models in a separate project is if you're writing an application that will support more than one database system for storing data. In that case you might have something like this (in the assembly `GregThomas.MyApp.DataAccess.Common`:

```
namespace GregThomas.MyApp.DataAccess.Common
{
    public interface ISprocketRepository
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Sprocket>> GetAllAsync();
    }

    public class Sprocket
    {
        // All the properties of a sprocket would be here
    }
}
```

You'd then have separate assemblies for each of the database providers that you wanted to support for example, in the assembly `GregThomas.MyApp.DataAccess.SqlServer`:

```
namespace GregThomas.MyApp.DataAccess.SqlServer
{
    public sealed class SprocketRepository : ISprocketRepository
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Sprocket>> ISprocketRepository.GetAllAsync()
        {
            // Code to retrieve sprockets from a SQL Server database here
        }
    }
}
```

Each of your database specific assemblies would reference the *.Common* assembly in order to be able to implement the appropriate interfaces and to access the models.